# Task for telegram bot

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rack, telegram-bot

I wrote a telegram bot on ruby with the help of rack. My questions is what can help me do this task. I need bot to send one message when starts_at field of my `activerecord` object will be equal to now. Basically I need to perform this task all the time so it monitor my database and send this message. I thought about something like `delayed_job`, don't know how it can help me to achieve my goal.

I need to close the event at a specific time:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  def close
    if starts_at == Time.now
      send_message("Some farewell message")
    end
  end
end
```

I need to check all the time if this event is ready to close and send a message after this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages. You need to help us help you. Your question is not well defined. What have you tried? Show us the minimum code to demonstrate it. Currently we'd have to define things in broad terms which leave too much room for interpretation. Imagine someone walked into a room with your question on a piece of paper, handed it to you and walked away. What would you need to see? What questions would you ask them? Then put that into your question.

Comment: @theTinMan Thank you, I understand my question is really unclear, hope this chunk of code will help

Answer (score 0):

You don't tell us what datatype your `starts_at` field is, but odds are really good that you'll almost never find an instant where `starts_at` is equal to `Time.now` so

```
if starts_at == Time.now
```

will usually fail.

`Time.now` has a granularity well beyond a second. This is from the [Time class documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Time.html):

> All times may have fraction. Be aware of this fact when comparing times with
>   each other -- times that are apparently equal when displayed may be different
>   when compared.

and from the [`Time#to_f` documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Time.html#method-i-to_f):

```
t = Time.now
"%10.5f" % t.to_f   #=> "1270968744.77658"
t.to_i              #=> 1270968744
```

If you're using a DateTime or Time field it's going to be very hard to match that microsecond. Instead, you need to change your code from using `==` to `<=` which will trigger whenever `start_time` is less than or equal to `Time.now`, assuming it's a compatible field of course.

Change:

```
if starts_at == Time.now
```

to:

```
if starts_at <= Time.now
```

and it should work better.

Alternately, you can make your `starts_at` field be an integer or fixnum and then change the values in it to integers, then compare using `Time#to_i` which results in just the seconds, not the sub-seconds:

```
[1] (pry) main: 0> foo = Time.now
2017-01-25 15:21:08 -0700
[2] (pry) main: 0> foo.to_f
1485382868.014835
[3] (pry) main: 0> foo.to_i
1485382868
```

But you'll still want to use `<=` instead of `==`.

Here's something to mull over:

```
foo = Time.now
bar = Time.now
foo # => 2017-01-25 15:25:42 -0700
bar # => 2017-01-25 15:25:42 -0700
foo.to_f # => 1485383142.157932
bar.to_f # => 1485383142.1579342
foo.to_i # => 1485383142
bar.to_i # => 1485383142
```

Even at full-speed, Ruby still returns a different time for `foo` vs. `bar`, and in that gap your code would miss firing. `to_i` gives you a one-second granularity but that's still not enough, hence the need for `<=`.